Random Occuring Error Durring PointTransformer Inference
I am woking on an optimization problem which includes obtaining the softmax output from the PointTransformer. I am using a genetic algorithm, NSGAII, where I want to maximize 3 objectives, where one objective is computing the difference between two softmax outputs, therefore I have to do inference on a point cloud (the point cloud is a portion from the Vaihingen dataset) many times during the execution of the algorithm. The problem is that this error occurs sometimes, and sometims the algorithm finishes without any problems. The error that I get is the following:
Progress:  0%|                                   | 0/20000 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Step 1 | ?(sl:0xp)
Progress: 20%|##                   | 400/20000 [09:21<41:27, 1.55it/s]


Traceback (most recent call last):
return self.model(input_features).detach().cpu().numpy()
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
p, f, r = self.encoders[i](points[i], feats[i], row_splits[i])
feat = self.relu(self.transformer2(point, feat, row_splits))
feak_k = queryandgroup(self.nsmaple, f)
idx = knn_batch(points)
return ans.neighbors_index.reshape(-1, self.nsample)
RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 8]' is invalid for input of size 799994

There is not much randomness, I randomly sample indices from the point cloud at the beginning and use them through the algorithm run. The points in the pointcloud do not change their positions, so the point cloud is almost the same through the algorithm run.
I initially thought that by adding noise to the point cloud, the points get shifted and the point cloud becomes very sparse and the knn cannot sample a sufficient amount of points and hence leads to this error. However, the error persists even if I do not add any noise and the point cloud is the same after each generation.
I also suspected that it could be a memory issue, however, I wrote the inference part correctly. The function looks like this:
    def compute_softmax(self, pointcloud: LabeledPointCloud) -> np.ndarray:
        selected_indices = self.get_pointcloud_indices(pointcloud)
        points = np.asarray(pointcloud.points)[selected_indices, :]
        colors = np.asarray(pointcloud.colors)[selected_indices, :]
        intensities = np.asarray(pointcloud.intensities)[selected_indices].reshape(-1, 1)
        num_returns = np.asarray(pointcloud.num_of_returns)[selected_indices].reshape(-1, 1)
        features = torch.Tensor(np.hstack((points, colors, intensities, num_returns))).to(self.device)
        return self.do_inference(features)

    def do_inference(self, features: torch.Tensor) -> np.ndarray:
        input_features = construct_point_transformer_input(features, self.device)
        with torch.no_grad():
            softmax_output = self.model(input_features).detach().cpu().numpy()
            return softmax_output

def construct_point_transformer_input(features: torch.Tensor, device: str) -> InputWrapper:
    num_points, in_channels = features.size()
    batch_size = 1
    xyz = features[:, :3]
    feat = features[:, :]

    xyz_flattened = xyz.reshape(num_points, 3).to(device)
    feat_flattened = feat.reshape(num_points, in_channels).to(device)
        
    row_splits = torch.tensor([i * num_points for i in range(batch_size + 1)], dtype=torch.int64, device=device)

    return InputWrapper(xyz_flattened.contiguous(), feat_flattened.contiguous(), row_splits)

The PointTransformer requires a data structure where the points and features are a sequence, hence I build the input in such a way. I also trained the model by constructing the input in the same way and had no problems.
